# Delimiting service area for electric network using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, service-area

I'm working on a study whose objective delimitation of the service area of an electric network with a type polyline I will like to know if there is a way whatever its nature, which will allow me to achieve the result below using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Minimum Bounding Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003q000000) to create this envelope polyline you're seeking.

Select the convex hull geometry type.

The output will be a polygon so convert it to a polyline.